# RSQLite Faster Subsetting of large Table?

Tags: sqlite, r

So I have a large dataset (see my previous question) where I need to subset it based on an ID which I have in another table

I use a statement like:

```
vars <- dbListFields(db, "UNIVERSE")
ids <- dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT ID FROM LIST1"

dbGetQuery(db,
    paste("CREATE TABLE SUB1 (",
    paste(vars,collapse=" int,"),
    ")"
)   )

dbGetQuery(db,
    paste("INSERT INTO SUB1 (",
        paste(vars,collapse=","),
        ") SELECT * FROM UNIVERSE WHERE
        UNIVERSE.ID IN (",
        paste(t(ids),collapse=","),
        ")"
)   )
```

The code runs (I may have missed a parenthesis above) but it takes a while since my table UNIVERSE is about 10 gigs in size. The major problem is I'm going to have to run this for many different tables "LIST#" to make "SUB#" and the subsets are not disjoint so I can't just delete the record from UNIVERSE when I'm done with it.

I'm wondering if I've gone about subsetting the wrong way or if there's other ways I can speed this up?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you find answer to your problem? There are a few different ways to handle this.

Comment: Do you want/need it to end up in phsycially different tables for each #?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an old question and I don't know if you found the solution or not.  If UNIVERSE.ID is a unique, non-NULL integer, setting it up as an 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY' should speed things up a lot.  There's some code and discussion here:
http://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-db%40stat.math.ethz.ch/msg00363.html

I don't know if using an inner join would speed things up or not; it might be worth a try too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index on UNIVERSE.ID? I'm no SQLite guru, but generally you want fields that you are going to query on to have indexes.

Comment: I don't think so. How can I check and/or add one?